# Example closed 1-form on $\mathbb{R}^3 -\{0\}$

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

It's maybe a silly question but I was wondering if there exists a closed 1-form $\alpha$ on the manifold $\mathbb{R}^3 -\{0\}$ of the form $$\frac{1}{x^2+y^2+z^2}(adx+bdy+cdz)$$ with $a, b$ and $c$ smooth function on $\mathbb{R}^3 - \{0\}$? (with $\alpha \neq 0$ and $\alpha \neq dx+dy+dz$ )

Extra: what if I also require that $d(adx+bdy+cdz) \neq 0$?

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: I tried to take the exterior derivative and used the fact that $dx \wedge dy$, $dx \wedge dz$ and $dy \wedge dz$ are linearly independent to find the following equations:$(\frac{a}{x^2+y^2+z^2})_y = (\frac{b}{x^2+y^2+z^2})_x$, $(\frac{a}{x^2+y^2+z^2})_z = (\frac{c}{x^2+y^2+z^2})_x$ and $(\frac{b}{x^2+y^2+z^2})_z = (\frac{c}{x^2+y^2+z^2})_y$, but I didn't found it that way..

Comment: $a=b=c=0$ seems to work.

Comment: I forgot to say that $\alpha$ is not $0$, I'm sorry.

Comment: $a=b=c=x^2+y^2+z^2$ seems to work then.

Comment: But then $\alpha = dx +dy +dz$ and then the denominator is gone, what I actually need

Comment: Let $g(x,y,z) = \ln(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)$.  Then $dg$ is an easy example.

Comment: @AdamHughes -- The minimalist approach is wonderful, isn't it?

Comment: @RobinGoodfellow I like to think so. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Since $\mathbb R^3\setminus \{0\}$ is simply-connected, a closed $1$-form must be exact; that is, of the form $df$ for some function $f$.

The requirement $\alpha = \frac{1}{x^2+y^2+z^2}(adx+bdy+cdz)$ with $a,b,c\in C^\infty(\mathbb R^3\setminus \{0\})$ is not saying anything other than $\alpha\in C^\infty(\mathbb R^3\setminus \{0\})$.  But from the comments it looks like you don't want cancellation: that is, $a,b,c$ should not vanish at the origin.

I'll impose an even more restrictive condition: $a,b,c$ homogeneous of degree $0$, that is constant on every line through the origin. Then $\alpha$ is homogeneous of degree $-2$, hence $f$ must be homogeneous of degree $-1$. The first such function that comes to mind is $$f(x,y,z)=(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{-1/2}$$
with
$$\alpha = df = -\frac{x\,dx+y\,dy+z\,dz}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}}$$

Comment: Thanks! And what if I impose the extra condition that $d(adx+bdy+cdz) \neq 0$?

Comment: I think this is satisfied by my example.